# Prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable on $(0, \infty)$ and not differentiable at $x=0$.

Tags: derivatives

Assume that $e^x$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$, prove that
$$f(x)= \frac{x}{1+e^{\dfrac{1}{x}}}; x\ne 0, f(0)=0$$ 
is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$. Is $f$ differentiable at $x=0$?

What I did is I used definition of derivative
$$\lim _{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$$ and then it became $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{1+e^{\dfrac{1}{h}}}$$ which doesn't exist. Because $$\lim_{h\to {0^+}}=0$$ but $$\lim_{h\to 0^-}=1$$ So it does not exist. 
So I guess it is not differentiable at $x=0$. 
But how to prove that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $(0, \infty)$ ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello. Please format math expressions in the right way using Latex commands. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Technically it isn't Latex. It's MathJax.

Comment: By the way, that limit actually exists, and it is 0. To prove differentiability away from 0, just use the chain rule (composition of differentiable functions is differentiable, but you have to be careful assuming WHERE the functions have to be differentiable)

Comment: Do you know LaTeX? I yes, you know almost everything needed to use MathJax.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Why are you so sure that the function is differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: @FeedbackLooper sorry, I wasn’t thinking about negative $h$. The way in which the question is written didn’t help, though

Comment: No problem. I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
f(x) = \frac{x}{1+e^{\frac{1}{x}}}
$$
which is a composition of the following functions: $f_1(x) = 1/x$, $f_2(x) = e^x$, $f_3(x) = 1+x$ and a multiplication by $x$. This is:
$$
f(x) = x(f_1 \circ f_3 \circ  f_2 \circ f_1)(x) = x f_1(f_3(f_2(f_1(x)))) 
$$
Note that $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are differentiable for $x\neq 0$ and multiplying with $x$ won't change that. Thus, you can safely apply the product rule + chain rule to obtain $f'(x)$ for $x\neq 0$:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{x+e^{\frac{1}{x}}(x+1)}{\left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}+1\right)^2x}
$$
and note that this expression is perfectly defined for $x\neq 0$. Interestingly, if you plot this function (e.g. in wolfram) you obtain the following:

[image]

Note that as you approach $x=0$ you get 0 from the positives and $1$ from the negatives, just as you obtained.

In short: $f'(x)$ is perfectly defined for $x\neq 0$ as we analyzed above. $f'(0)$ does not exist by the argument you made in your question (the limit does not exist).

Hope this clarifies something for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Hope you have a nice day!