# Stuck with Lagrange Multiplier with no solution

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Find the minimum value of $f(x,y,z) = xy + 2yz + 2xz$ subject to the constraint $xyz = 108$.

I just tried normal lagrange multiplier and after some hard time I found only one solution which is $(6,6,3)$.

 With the value of $f(6,6,3) = 108$. But I think this doesn't prove anything.
It is not the max point neither the min point since I tried $(108,1,1)$ and $(-1,-1,108)$. 
What should I do?

 I used wolframalpha and it says that there is no min and max point.
Is this true? What should I do?

 Thank you in advance

 And sorry I do not know LaTex

Effort in the picture[image: Effort]
[image: Wolfram]
[Link Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=1451afdfe5a25b2a316377c1cd488883)

Comment: I just input like I did in the picture

Comment: It is still the same. No max or min found

Comment: There can be local mins and maxes without there being global mins and maxes.

Comment: Please can you explain how to get the local minimum? Because I tried and now I am stuck. I need your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that $(6,6,3)$ is just a local minimum. All points close to this local minimum give a greater value of $f(x,y,z)$. However, this doesn't mean anything about the global behaviour of $f$.

To visualize this, lets look at a "slice" of $f(x,y,z)$. Consider
$$
\begin{aligned}
y &= x\\
z &= \frac{108}{xy}
\end{aligned}
$$

I chose $y=x$ since you obtained that the mimum complies that condition. However, instead of $z=x/2=y/2$ I only use the constraint $xyz=108$ in order to vary $x$ and look at what happens to $f$. This is, $f(x,y,z) = f\left(x,x,\frac{108}{x^2}\right)$ is a function of a single variable and looks like this:
[image]

The blue line is what happens for positive $x$. Clearly there is a local minimum, precisely at $x=6$ as you obtained. However, for negative $x$ (red line) $f$ has no lower bound. In fact, you can make $f$ as negative as you want if $x\to 0^-$. Hence, the "global minimum" does not exist.

The output of wolfram is consistent with this, no global minimum, but one local minimum.
[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very useful. Hope you have a great day!

Comment: No problem! you too.

Comment: Can you also help me solve this problem? I would really appreciate it. But I don't want to force you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221969/prove-that-fx-is-differentiable-on-0-inf-and-not-differentiable-at-x-0

Comment: I'll take a look. Also, if you found this question useful, you might want to consider marking it as "correct".